# Resolution lower than monitor

Tags: graphics, display-resolution

So my monitor is 1920x1080 but my computer is locked at 1024x768 and any xrandr commands will make it say “ Failed to get size of gamma for output default”
Can anyone help me get it back to 1920x1080

Specs are: Amd ryzen 9 5900x, Amd Radeon 6900xt

Comment: What are the exact commands you are using and the full output of each command? Use copy/paste into your question.  When is the last time the screen resolution was set to the native resolution and what has changed on your system since then?  Is the native resolution available in system settings?

Comment: Please start with your OS & release; those details give us the best indication as to what software stack you're using (for LTS releases providing the kernel stack used is also helpful (LTS releases have two choices chosen at install time) but currently we haven't been provided anything)

Comment: Are you using nomodeset?

Comment: Would it help to know this happened after having to completely reinstalling my desktop environment and manager